# to show arrays in a row, not in column in jupyter notebook

Tags: python

I am using jupyter notebook, this code

```
A = np.arange(1,7).reshape((2,3))
B = np.arange(7,13).reshape((3,2))
print(A,B)
```

outputs

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]] [[ 7  8]
 [ 9 10]
 [11 12]]
```

which is not friendly to check.

Is there a way to have the output look like this

[image]

or this

```
[1 2 3] [7 8]
[4 5 6] [ 9 10]
        [11 12]
```

the ideal output does not have to be the same as the above, just something like that, to stack the arrays horizontally.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: So you are trying to format the way `print` is printing the arrays?

Comment: @wundermahn I guess I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you convert the arrays to strings, each spans multiple lines, so printing one after the other doesn't cause them to appear horizontally because the line-breaks from the first array move the second one down vertically.

Here's a function which concatenates them row-by-row instead of as strings:

```py
def print_arrays(*arrs):
    # split each string into rows
    arrs = [str(a).split('\n') for a in arrs]
    # count how many rows are needed for all arrays side-by-side
    height = max(len(a) for a in arrs)
    # find the width of each matrix
    widths = [max(len(row) for row in a) for a in arrs]
    # add empty rows at the bottom of any matrices as needed
    arrs = [a + [''] * (height - len(a)) for a in arrs]
    # pad each row to be the correct width for that matrix
    arrs = [[row.ljust(w) for row in a] for a, w in zip(arrs, widths)]
    # join the rows together
    result = [' '.join(row) for row in zip(*arrs)]
    # print the result
    print(*result, sep='\n')
```

Example:

```py
>>> A, B = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
>>> print_arrays(A, B)
[[1 2]  [[1 2 3] 
 [3 4]]  [4 5 6] 
         [7 8 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try and define your own print function.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(1,7).reshape((2,3))
B = np.arange(7,13).reshape((3,2))
#print(A,B)

def print_array(x):
    for row in range(x.shape[0]):
        print(x[row])

print_array(A)
print_array(B)
```

Yields:

```
[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[7 8]
[ 9 10]
[11 12]
```

Comment: The output is quite close. Thank you so much. I updated the OP just now.